# How should the data part be written for ajax for it to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been struggling with this part for a while now. I've realised that my list gets personName and personLastName inserted instead of my values from the text fields but I can't seem to make the real values get inserted.

Insert.php is well tested and works.

How should the data part be written?

My html

```
<input type="text" id="firstName1" name="name2"id="first3"><br>
<input type="text" id="lastName1" name="last2" id="last3"><br>
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="Add">
```

My javascript.

```
$(function() {

  $('#btn').click(function() {
    alert('pressed');

    $.ajax({
      url: 'insert.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        'first': 'personName',
        'last': 'personLastName'
      },
      success: function(msg) {
        alert('Added'); 
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` must be unique within a web page... I often say that. But it's the first time I say an `id` must be defined only once per element. So that is the first issue.

Now, in your `data` object, `personName` and `personLastName` are strings. That is what is sent.

If you want the value from the inputs, use the `id`.

Something like:

```
data: {
  'first': $("#firstName1").val(),
  'last': $("#lastName1").val()
},
```

And remove the second `id` for each input in the HTML markup.